# How to update table in mysql using session id for more than 1000 users in app?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an app, Now i am successfully logged in using following code,Now i want to create session for login user and also to maintain session in whole app and by using login user **session** id i want to update the records in mysql table. Can i update the records for more than 1000 users using session id? How do i do this? Please give **suggestions**.

**login file**

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    private EditText editTextPhone;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    public static final String PHONE_NAME = "PHONE";

    String phone;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        editTextPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view){
        phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        login(phone,password);

    }



    private void login(final String phone, String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String phone = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];

                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://example.in/login.php");

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SearchActivity1.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PHONE_NAME, phone);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(phone, password);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//php

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select * from users10 where phone='$phone' and password='$password'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($check)){
echo 'success';
}else{
echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You probably mean a session in php. You can set session variables (like a login status or user rights or the user id) and use them in your code, e.g. if you set a variable "this_is_admin=1" in your login.php (depending on the login), you can then, on another php-page, check if that variable is set then do something different there than for normal users. You can of course add them to any sql query you use, but I'm not sure what you mean by "Can i update the records for more than 1000 users using session id?" (though the answer is "yes, you can do that").

Comment: i want to update records in mysql table for each user which is logged in so how can i do this?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.